# Getting the user setting for cursor blink speed on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm developing an OpenGL application which is doing some custom UI stuff, and for text editing I'd like to honor the user-setting for the cursor blink speed.

On windows I use:

```
UINT GetCaretBlinkTime(void);
```

But I've been unable to find an equivalent on OS X, the only hits I get when searching are related to setting the blink speed instead of reading it.

My application is written in C++, so a C/Obj-C/Obj-C++ solution should work.